# How to troubleshoot `super()` calls finding incorrect type and obj?

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance, super

I have a decorator in my library which takes a user's class and creates a new version of it, with a new metaclass, it is supposed to completely replace the original class. Everything works; except for `super()` calls:

```
class NewMeta(type):
 pass

def deco(cls):
 cls_dict = dict(cls.__dict__)
 if "__dict__" in cls_dict:
   del cls_dict["__dict__"]
 if "__weakref__" in cls_dict:
   del cls_dict["__weakref__"]
 return NewMeta(cls.__name__, cls.__bases__, cls_dict)

@deco
class B:
 def x(self):
  print("Hi there")

@deco
class A(B):
 def x(self):
  super().x()
```

Using this code like so, yields an error:

```
>>> a = A()
>>> a.x()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in x
TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

Some terminology:

- The source code class `A` as produced by `class A(B):`.
- The produced class `A*`, as produced by `NewMeta(cls.__name__, cls.__bases__, cls_dict)`.

`A` is established by Python to be the `type` when using `super` inside of the methods of `A*`. How can I correct this?

There's some suboptimal solutions like calling `super(type(self), self).x`, or passing `cls.__mro__` instead of `cls.__bases__` into the `NewMeta` call (so that `obj=self` always inherits from the incorrect `type=A`). The first is unsustainable for end users, the 2nd pollutes the inheritance chains and is confusing as the class seems to inherit from itself.

Python seems to introspect the source code, or maybe stores some information to automatically establish the `type`, and in this case, I'd say it is failing to do so;

How could I make sure that inside of the methods of `A` `A*` is established as the `type` argument of argumentless `super` calls?

Comment: While there might be a way to fix it, this is basically the equivalent of trying to change the type of an existing object. Why not simply define `class B(metaclass=NewMeta)`?

Comment: Because `A` and `B` are defined by the user, and `deco` is a part of my library. Transparently to the user it creates a new metaclass composed of the class's existing metaclasses, adding a few magic extras. Sadly setting a metaclass of an existing class object is impossible. I updated my question, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument-free `super` uses the `__class__` cell, which is a regular function closure.

> #### Data Model: [Creating the class object](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#creating-the-class-object)
>
> `__class__` is an implicit closure reference created by the compiler if any methods in a class body refer to either `__class__` or `super`.

```py
>>> class E:
...    def x(self):
...        return __class__  # return the __class__ cell
...
>>> E().x()
__main__.E
>>> # The cell is stored as a __closure__
>>> E.x.__closure__[0].cell_contents is E().x() is E
True
```

Like any other closure, this is a *lexical* relation: it refers to `class` scope in which the method was literally defined. Replacing the class with a decorator still has the methods refer to the original class.

---

The simplest fix is to explicitly refer to the *name* of the class, which gets rebound to the newly created class by the decorator.

```py
@deco
class A(B):
    def x(self):
        super(A, self).x()
```

Alternatively, one can change the content of the `__class__` cell to point to the new class:

```py
def deco(cls):
    cls_dict = dict(cls.__dict__)
    cls_dict.pop("__dict__", None)
    cls_dict.pop("__weakref__", None)
    new_cls = NewMeta(cls.__name__, cls.__bases__, cls_dict)
    for method in new_cls.__dict__.values():
        if getattr(method, "__closure__", None) and method.__closure__[0].cell_contents is cls:
            method.__closure__[0].cell_contents = new_cls
    return new_cls
```

Comment: I wonder how robust changing `__class__` is. (Or maybe more to the point, if there's anything *else* lurking behind the scene that should be updated as well.)

Comment: @chepner At least not for `super` according to its spec. Interestingly enough, the ``__class__`` *attribute* (slot? property?) is recreated automatically for the new class. Of course the original class may have run arbitrary code, a descriptor may have bound to the class in `__set_name__`, or similar; as always there may be meta dragons when doing meta programming.